# occur invalid syntax error in python when using elif statement

Tags: python

when I put elif, invalid syntax error occur.

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> elif age < 12:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    elif age < 12:
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Above it causes error, and I do not know why.

Comment: The error says that is line 1.  You can't have `elif` as the very first thing.  It must come after an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Hi `elif` statements are always use after an `if` statement

```
if <condition>:
    <code for if statement>
elif <condition>:
    <code for elif statement>
else:
    <code for else statement>
```

python will first check the if condition. If it is not true it will go to the elif
condition. If it fails to we can use else, a condition less statement which will execute if all condition fail.

hope it helped :)

Comment: hi it seems you are using python in interactive mode. it is recommended to use script mode.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much, I used in that mode, and it worked.